# Drawable XML height not preserved by View?

Tags: android, android-view, android-drawable, layer-list

I have a drawable xml `mybackground.xml` as below with a height of 50dp

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:endColor="#00FF00"
                android:startColor="#00FFFF" />
            <size android:height="50dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

If I use it as below in `ImageView`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@drawable/mybackground"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```

or in `FrameLayout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@drawable/mybackground"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```

It is shown as

[image]

However if I use `View` instead,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<View xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@drawable/mybackground"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```

it is shown as

[image]

The `View` is not preserving the `height` defined on the `mybackground.xml`. Did I miss anything?

Comment: I reported the issue in https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/110698210

Comment: good. I hope this issue has been fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at your question and was curious to compare the View class with the other classes. As a result, there was no part to calculate the size of the background in the view class measure (), and in the measure () of the FrameLayout, ImageView, etc., the dimension was determined considering the size of the background. This seems to be a simple conceptual issue.

Comment: Or perhaps it's a bug in the View code. All views should handle this in a consistent manner.